# Array.push() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to retrieve some data that I'm fetching from an api so that I can build a chart with Chart.js with that retrieved data.

The problem is that I am declaring 2 arrays to store the data returned by the api, but when I push the data it returns undefined and I can't understand why.

Here's the function responsible for what I described above:

```
async function getChartData(){

    const xdata = []
    const ydata = []

    const data = await (await fetch('http://projetoti.test/api/api.php?nome=all')).json()

    await data.forEach(async (sensor, index) => {

        let sensor_data = await (await fetch(`http://projetoti.test/api/api.php?nome=${sensor.name}&history=true`)).json()

        let xtemp_arr = []
        let ytemp_arr = []

        Object.keys(sensor_data).forEach(sData => {
            xtemp_arr.push(sensor_data[sData].value)
            ytemp_arr.push(sensor_data[sData].time)
        })

        xdata.push(xtemp_arr.slice())
        ydata.push(ytemp_arr.slice())
    })

    console.log(xdata)
    return { xdata, ydata}

}
```

The confusing part is, when I `console.log(xdata)` inside the `data.forEach()` it consoles the expected even when it quits the forEach() xdata consoles the expected but it returns undefined.

I know that in JavaScript when we push an array what is actually happening is that the reference of the array is being copied.

So I tried to solve that by making a copy of the temporary arrays with `.slice()`.
But still, xdata and ydata are returning undefined.

Note: Here is the print of the `console.log(xdata): [output of console.log(xdata)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Theuh.png)` 
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `await data.forEach()` does not do what I believe you may be expecting it to. The `forEach()` method returns `undefined` and the `await` will return immediately. The statements afterwards, `console.log(xdata)` and `return { xdata, ydata}` will then execute immediately afterwards. Meanwhile, the function within the `forEach()` will still be running, meaning that inside this function, the `.push()` calls happen **after** `getChartData()` has already `return`ed and hence why you might not be getting what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know that `forEach()` returned `undefined`, but now it makes sense to me.